# Why is there an error being thrown in the while statement?

Tags: java

The following code throws an error in the `while` statement. I have tried to initialize the variable `theInput`, but it continues to cause an error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{   
    int size = 19;
    int count = 0;
    int theNumber = (int)(Math.random()*(size+1));

    do
    {
        String user = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a guess!");
        int theInput = Integer.parseInt(user);
        count++;

        if(theInput < theNumber)
        {
            System.out.println("Guess higher!");
        }
        else if(theInput < theNumber)
        {
            System.out.println("Guess lower!");
        }
        else if(theInput == theNumber)
        {
            System.out.println("Congratulations! You have found the number!");
        }
    } while(**theInput** != theNumber);

}
```

This throws the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: userInput cannot be resolved to a variable

What is causing this error?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Slaw "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 userInput cannot be resolved to a variable"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `theInput` is out of scope by the time you get to comparing it to `theNumber`. Simply split off its declaration and initialization.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {   
    int size = 19; // Declare AND initialize
    int count = 0; // Declare AND initialize
    int theNumber = (int)(Math.random()*(size+1)); // Declare AND initialize
    int theInput; // Declare but don't initialize yet

    do
    {
        String user = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a guess!");
        theInput = Integer.parseInt(user);
        count++;

        if (theInput < theNumber)
        {
            System.out.println("Guess higher!");
        }
        else if (theInput < theNumber) // Shouldn't this be greater than?
        {
            System.out.println("Guess lower!");
        }
        else if (theInput == theNumber)
        {
            System.out.println("Congratulations! You have found the number!");
        }
    } while (theInput != theNumber);

   }
}
```

And maybe you should do something about the potential `NumberFormatException`, but that might be getting ahead in your textbook.

Comment: Oh wow! I didn't think of that. Thanks too on catching the greater than typo. I just couldn't seem to resolve it haha so thanks for helping me out!